# How to solve problems when submitting form and inserting into DB?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I can't insert into DB data from form of HTML code. When submit form  it's not working.

Code bellow represents source of problem.

```php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    include '_dbconnect.php';

    $User_id = (isset($_POST['User_id']) ? $_POST['User_id'] : '');

    $asset_id = (isset($_POST['asset_id']) ? $_POST['asset_id'] : '');

    $issued_asset = (isset($_POST['issued_on']) ? $_POST['issued_on'] : '');


    $sql = "INSERT INTO `userasset` (`User_id`,`asset_id`, `issued_on`) VALUES (:User_id,:asset_id,:issued_on); ";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $pdoQuery_run = $stmt->execute(array(':User_id' => $User_id, `:asset_id` => $asset_id, `:issued_on` => $issued_on));

    $smt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT User_id From userasset');
    $smt->execute();
    $data = $smt->fetchAll();


    $smt1 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT asset_id From userasset');
    $smt1->execute();
    $data1 = $smt1->fetchAll();

}
```

Comment: Is there a question ?

Comment: sorry new to all this i am stuck and errors are coming that i am not able to resolve. error : Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\boot\issueasset.php on line 181

Comment: @RipudamanSingh please add your comment under the question you asked by edit button

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `$issued_asset` to `$issued_on` which you using after in the  execute method.

Use
`$issued_on = (isset($_POST['issued_on']) ? $_POST['issued_on'] : '');`

Instead of:
`$issued_asset = (isset($_POST['issued_on']) ? $_POST['issued_on'] : '');`

Because after you are using:
`` $pdoQuery_run = $stmt->execute(array(':User_id' => $User_id, `:asset_id` => $asset_id, `:issued_on` => $issued_on)); ``

Comment: hi its still not working . error : Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\boot\issueasset.php on line 181

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number in C:\xampp\htdocs\boot\issueasset.php on line 180